# Polynomial of the term of convergent series converges

Tags: real-analysis

Let $p$ be a polynomial with no constant term. If $b_j > 0$ for every $j$ and if $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}{b_j}$ converges then prove that the series $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}{p(b_j)}$ converges.

I immediately ruled out ratio test as the approach since I can do nothing with polynomials in both numerator and denominator. I guess root test is the right path since each term is a polynomial and we can just pick out some terms after expansion. But the degree of each term being different is troublesome, and I fail to find a way to develop inequalities that connect with the condition given.

Ideas?

Comment: As you know, you are supposed to share with us your attempts at making progress on this problem.

Comment: I tried root test and and ratio test but none of them succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}{b_j}$ converges, we have 
$\lim_{j\to\infty}b_j=0.$
In particularly, $b_j$ is bounded, i.e. $$\tag{1}|b_j|\leq M.$$
By assumption, $p$ is a polynomial with no constant term, i.e. 
$$p(x)=a_n x^n+\cdots a_2 x^2+a_1 x,$$
which implies
$$|p(b_j)|=\Big|(a_n b_j^{n-1}+\cdots a_2 b_j+a_1) b_j\Big|\leq 
\Big(|a_n| M^{n-1}+\cdots |a_2| M+|a_1|\Big)b_j$$
by $(1)$ and the assumption that $b_j>0$. 
Since $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}{b_j}$ converges,  $\sum_{j}|p(b_j)|$ converges by [comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test). And since $\sum_{j}|p(b_j)|$ converges, $\sum_{j}p(b_j)$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

Let's generalize: If $f$ satisfies $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0)$ exists, then $\sum f(b_n)$ converges.

Proof: $|f(x)/x| = |(f(x)-f(0))/(x-0)| \le |f'(0)| + 1$ for small nonzero $x.$ Thus for such $x, |f(x)| \le (|f'(0)| + 1)|x|.$ Because $b_n \to 0,$ for large $n$ we have $$|f(b_n)| \le (|f'(0)| + 1)|b_n| = (|f'(0)| + 1)b_n.$$ We know $\sum b_n < \infty,$ so $ \sum (|f'(0)| + 1)b_n < \infty.$ Therefore $\sum |f(b_n)| < \infty.$ Because absolute convergence implies convergence, $\sum f(b_n)$ converges as desired.